# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. Simple Routing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

I am working on a small web project and try to get along with the basic routing in node.js & express.
The Server starts properly and shows all Websites but when go to the second page to load some (simple) server data the error occurs.

Server Code :

```
const express = require('express'); //importiert express modul
const app = express(); //und bildet eine Express-Application
const server = require('http').createServer(app);//importiert http modul und bildet Server


/*

 die dateien (bilder, skripte, css und html dokumente (public ordner))
  werden statisch aus dem jeweiligen Verzeichnis geladen
  kann später so "GET localhost/style.css" aufgerufen werden
  */
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
  app.use('/javascript', express.static(__dirname + '/public/javascripts'));
  app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/stylesheets'));

/*
 So wird die index.html Datei beim Zugriff auf den Server (http://127.0.0.1:1337/) ausgegeben
 Die index.html wird beim Zugriff auf den Server ausgegeben
 */

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;


//Server auf port 1337
server.listen(1337);
console.log('Der Server läuft nun unter http://127.0.0.1: 1337');
```

Routing code in routing folder

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var jsondata = "DATA";

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/api/alleAssets', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Ich bin in der Methode');
  res.send({bla :'bla'})
});

module.exports = router;
```

Sorry for some Commands ins German. I think they won´t be important to understand such basic code.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
This is the console log and the error message when going on the second page:
(The body is connected to an onload function)

```
> peasec@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec
> node ./bin/www

Der Server läuft nun unter http://127.0.0.1: 1337
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\app.js:41:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\Tim\Documents\University\UIP\PearSecExpress\PearSec\peasec\app.js:30:3
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you are.recieving when opening the second page?

Comment: Posted the full console log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a templating engine to render pages. Examples for templating engines are Jade, EJS etc. The below line of code will set your templating Engine to EJS, and use it to render HTML content.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Using EJS as templating engine needs your public files to be .ejs extension. Following link will help you get a basic understanding of how EJS works.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Give it a shot and let me know if it works or not.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention, EJS is only required when you use dynamic content in your HTML page. If you are having a static page, you can simply send the path of that static page.

```
res.sendFile('/path/to/page.html');
```